# Any way to abort hide on q-dialog?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dialog, quasar

I'm trying to build a confirmation modal into a dialog containing form inputs, so i can notify the user that his changes will be lost if he closes without saving. This means displaying the modal every time the user has made changes to the input values and tries to quit the dialog (via click outside/escape button/close button). Now if the user decides to go back and save his changes i'll have to prevent the hide event which has been fired.

The dialog is invoked via the quasar plugin.

I already tried using the @before-hide event listener to listen for and prevent the hide event but there is no event emitted.

Any other way to do it?

Comment: The [Quasar Dialog plugin](https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog) is different than the [Quasar Dialog component](https://quasar.dev/vue-components/dialog).  The plugin is not as customizable, for example it does not emit events like `@before-hide`. If you want those events and usage of `v-model` which would give you exact control of the showing/hiding of the dialog, make sure to use the **component**, not the plugin.

Comment: Sounds valid. That would mean that i have to create a variable for each dialog in the parent as well as in the child. Can't use ref because the dialog is not in the DOM until opened. Any ideas on how to open the dialog from parent component?

Comment: Captured the event using your approach. Sadly the event is not cancelable :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event you can use to stop the dialog from closing is `@update:model-value` which is called whenever the v-model value changes.  By setting the v-model back to `true` in the callback, the dialog will not close.

I made a proof-of-concept in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/quasarframework-gyweh1?file=src%2FApp.vue) using the QDialog component.  It may not match your exact business logic but hopefully it's enough to help you.  If not, let me know.

```html
<q-dialog v-model="dialog1" @update:model-value="checkForSave">
```

```js
const checkForSave = () => {
  // if user has saved, allow close to happen
  if (saved.value) return;
  else {
    //keep current dialog open
    dialog1.value = true;
    //open second dialog letting user know they haven't saved
    dialog2.value = true;
  }
};
```

Comment: Didn't know you could use refs as a v-model. Thanks for taking the trouble to create a stackblitz :) was really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

it is simple you can use dialog validation for your input to prevent closing

see this link : https://quasar.dev/quasar-plugins/dialog#basic-validation

```
$q.dialog({
          title: 'Prompt',
          message: 'What is your name? (Minimum 3 characters)',
          prompt: {
            model: '',
            isValid: val => val.length > 2, // << here is the magic
            type: 'text' // optional
          },
          cancel: true,
          persistent: true
        }).onOk(data => {
          // console.log('>>>> OK, received', data)
        })
      }
```

or you can use onCancel event to save input data

```
.onCancel(async () => {
      await saveInputs();
    });
```

Comment: Not really what i was looking for